# What features, items, or spells allow dodging as a bonus action other than Monk's Patient Defense?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm looking for features, spells, or items that trigger Dwarven Fortitude without the use of Ki points.

Dwarven Fortitude:

> Whenever you take the Dodge action in combat, you can spend one Hit Die to heal yourself. Roll the die, add your Constitution modifier, and regain a number of hit points equal to the total (minimum of 1).

The feat requires performing the Dodge action. As such, *Sword of the Paruns*, *Blur*, *Foresight*, or any other thing that gives the benefits of the Dodge action would not trigger the feat, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Are you interested in just *any* feature or, more specifically, a list of all of them? To me, the latter would be a better question

Comment: Ah. I suppose that's a better way to phrase the question, so that if multiple are found they can all be presented.

Comment: Generally I don't say this but, please wait a while before accepting an answer. While the first answer may be the most accurate to your situation it is still wise to get multiple answers before accepting an answer so as to further stimulate discussion for the question asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Almost nothing lets you take the Dodge action as a bonus action

There is, of course, the Monk's [Patient Defense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#Ki-228) feature:

> You can spend 1 ki point to take the Dodge action as a bonus action on your turn.

And... that's it...

The only things even close would be things like the Fighter's Action Surge feature, which grants an entire new action and using the [*shapechange*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shapechange) or a *polymorph* spell to turn into a creature that can *already* Dodge as a bonus action or something else along those lines, such as the [Fastieth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/fastieth) (a Eberron dinosaur).

---

Note, this is a Community Wiki post, feel free to edit it to add in other methods

Comment: I no longer have access to most of DnD Beyond (my DM hasn't been keeping up his subscription since we haven't met in a year), but I swear there was a Rogue class feature that allowed Dodge as a bonus action.  It might have been the general one they all get, or an addition/replacement to it from a subclass.

Comment: @gatherer818 Rogues get Cunning Action, which allows Dash, Disengage, and Hide as bonus actions, and some archetypes expand it but none that allow Dodge that I can find. I don't have access to them all.

Comment: @KamilDrakari yeah, that sounds right, thanks for setting me straight <3